# How to Install Xubuntu Inside Windows (no downloading)

Tags: installation, wubi, xubuntu

I have these files.

**ubuntu-12.04.3-wubi-amd64.tar.xz**

**ubuntu-12.04.1-i386.iso**

**xubuntu-12.04-i386.iso**

I want to install **Xubuntu inside windows**.

I have **tried** with ***wubi.exe --dimagepath=path*** but still it gives an error

Cannot download metalink and therefore iso...

**Please Help me** with this.

Is there any way to tell **wubi to pick up xubuntu's iso from my pc**?

**Thanks**

Comment: You should first install Ubuntu, and then inside Ubuntu install Xubuntu using `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix versions of `wubi.exe` (and as far as Wubi is concerned, 12.04 is not the same as 12.04.1/2/3).

You can install Xubuntu using the ISO you have as long as you use the correct `wubi.exe` i.e. the ones dated 24 April 2012 from [old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/)

To do this:

1. Save the ISO with the correct version of `wubi.exe` in the same folder
2. Disconnect from the Internet (avoid the `mds5sum` check)
3. Run `wubi.exe`

Note this assumes that the Xubuntu ISO you have is good.

Comment: It is still the same. It still downloads the xubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent. I have downloaded it manually but no use. How can I tell wubi to use this iso. And now even ubuntu is not installing.

Comment: And by --skipmd5check it does not give an option to install inside windows

Comment: If it's downloading 12.04.3 then you are using the wrong version of `wubi.exe`. And disconnect from the internet (step 2).